# include d3.js into angular2 project

Tags: d3.js, typescript, npm, angular

I'm trying to use d3.js library in a MEAN application using angular2.

This is what I've done:

```
npm install d3
tsd install d3
```

In mypage.ts (where I want to display the d3.js graph)

```
// <reference path="../../../typings/d3/d3.d.ts" />
import * as d3 from "d3/d3";
```

But I get this error: `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'd3/d3'.`

My typings folder structure:

```
typings
- d3
    d3.d.ts
- index.d.ts
```

index.d.ts looks like:

```
/// <reference path="modules/d3/d3.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share more of your config files?

Answer (score 3):

I stuck =somewhere else in D3 with Angular2, my search for the solution lead me here. It worked for me this way:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

See if it works for you as well.